# Where is "./" in php.ini extensions directory pointing to?

Tags: php

I don't want to look like a noob, but this is really annoying me. Do you know where does the

```
; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
extension_dir = "./"
```

pointing to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`./` points to the current directory.

**Edit**

I haven't found any definition of what the current directory is while parsing a `php.ini` file, [this post suggests](http://www.phpbuilder.com/board/showthread.php?t=7109741) that it is relative to the `php.ini` files location.

Comment: Thanks Anders, I kind of thought that, but I don't know if it's php.ini's current directory, or if it's something else's current directory, perhaps php engine file (i don't know if that's the term) or (most likely not) apache's... :S

Comment: That was a far more difficult question, I've updated my answer with a source but I haven't been able to verify it.

Comment: Hey Anders, I don't know if this is a good practice or not, but since changing the "ext = /." line to something else was breaking the other extensions (which I couldn't find anywhere). I ended up using the directory structure on the extension=/my/directory/structure/extension.so and it worked. Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 3):

Just adding in for future searches

Running `phpinfo` on the `cli (php -a<enter>phpinfo();<enter>)` gave me this among the output.

```
extension_dir => /usr/lib/php/20131226 => /usr/lib/php/20131226
```

Comment: For easier use, try this: ```php -r 'phpinfo();' | grep extension_dir```

Comment: Finding the directory is one thing, but understanding why it uses that one is still a bit mysterious to me (the value in `php.ini` is commented out by default).  Mine happens to be in `/etc/lib64/php/modules/`, which is obviously a feature of the 64-bit architecture.

Comment: @cartbeforehorse  Check out the bottom part of my answer and see if that answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that "current directory" is, as far as PHP is concerned, whatever directory "pwd" prints.

The easiest way to see this is to run `php -r 'echo getcwd();'`

I can also determine this is by typing `zend_extension="xdebug.so"` inside my php.ini . Next, I create two folders anywhere: One empty, and the other I copy my xdebug.so into. 
When I open a terminal inside my empty folder and run `php`, it generates a warning about not being able to find xdebug.so. In contrast, if I open the terminal in the folder with the extension and run php at the prompt, there are no warnings.

I couldn't determine where this maps to when running php through apache. I tried the document root, HTTPD_ROOT, /usr/bin. Nothing. I'm making this note incase someone who knows more about apache can shed some light on this.

As far as, extension_dir's default location. That is compiled in. You can find the value for your extension_dir by finding the file `build-defs.h.` It's defined in the macro `PHP_EXTENSION_DIR` build-defs.h is created by a template file during the configure stage of compilation.